# Bind array into select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, foreach

I try to bind an array of values in this case `$ownco` in another select query but it wont work. How can I realize it, that all values becomes checked/passed in the second query?

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    $sql = "SELECT id_post
            FROM comments
            WHERE  username = $username
            ORDER BY id DESC"; // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
    if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
        // then after fetchColumn
        $ownco = $res->fetchAll();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, autor, date, longitude, latitude, title, text, town, time
            FROM posts
            WHERE  id = $ownco
            ORDER BY id DESC"; // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
    if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
        // then after fetchColumn
        $resultcom = $res->fetchAll();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont see `$owncomments` in your code

Comment: I don't see where you're "binding" any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your question.

- First of all, you accepted the the answer that doesn't answer it. Cheating on the rules?
- Second, your first query will never work, due to wrong SQL syntax AND lack of prepared statements.
- Third, `$ownco` doesn't contain the data structure you expect.
- Fourth, to bind an array with PDO is quite simple question, explained in many answers already and even in [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).
- Fifth, you don't need the second query at all. Instead you have to use `JOIN` in the first query.

Comment: I thought after google "implode" that this is the solution of my problem but now I checked the errors. I used pdo on many querys in my project but all works. Thanks for youre hints and the link.

Answer (score 0):

Change your second query as below

```
$sql = "SELECT id, autorid, autor, date, longitude, latitude, title, text, town, time 
        FROM posts
        WHERE  id in (" . implode(",",$ownco) . ")
        ORDER BY id DESC";
```